# Pink windows headers

Tags: macbook-pro, display, color

All windows headers are becoming pink after a while, like every several hours.
I have to go to Display settings and change the color profile to any other and back to default — this is the only solution.

Night shift does not affect this as well as the games with color profiles — default or not.

Any ideas on how to fix that?

See this when working without and with an external display.
MBP 13" M1, but the same issue was on the MBP 16".
Big Sur 11.2.2.

[image: pink]

[image: gray]

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below.